# settimeout() not working in async/await function javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an async/await function as such:

```
async myfunction() {
  //CSS transition
  setTimeout(() => {
    //another CSS transition
  }, 500)
  await ... .then(... => {...});  
}
```

The problem is, my CSS transition in the setTimeout() goes off after the code in the .then() of await. Is it possible to force all the code before .then() to run first? I believe this has to do with the async nature of setTimeout() conflicting with the async await, but I'm not sure how to go around it. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Just `await` the promisified `setTimeout`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance what promisified `setTimeout()`? I don't see one anywhere, just a normal one.

Comment: Adam.V, the 2017 update for the `sleep()` in the top answer is a promisified `setTimeout()` that is compatible with `await`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts OP just has to promisify the `setTimeout` and `await` it

Comment: create a promise for setTimeout and use Promise.all or just use await

Comment: I'm not really sure how to promisify the settimeout. How would I do that? Wouldn't I be left with two awaits?